# Python str() not called by list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

When I use list comprehension, I'm getting different results when I print a nested list of objects, compared to what happens if I just use a for loop.

```
class Feature:
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return 'f'

featList = [[Feature() for j in range(3)] for i in range(10)]

[print(str(f)) for f in [r for r in featList]]

for r in featList:
    [print(str(f)) for f in r]
```

The first print gives me back stuff like:

> [<**main**.Feature object at 0x0000026AB6371588>, <**main**.Feature
>   object at 0x0000026AB63BA8D0>, <**main**.Feature object at
>   0x0000026AB4966BE0>]

The second print gives me back "f" 30 times.

Comment: `[print(str(f)) for f in [r for r in featList]]` this returns the print function object into your list. That's just how it works. Though i don't know why you need to put print in your list .....

Comment: `f` isn't iterating over each individual `r`; it's iterating over a list of *lists* of `r`s

Comment: You're calling str on a list of objects, not on Feature. Although when converting a list to a string, it will call __repr__ to get a printable version of the object. Still, you should use loops because they make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are Iterating

```
featList = [[Feature() for j in range(3)] for i in range(10)]
```

list of lists of features

```
a = [f for f in [r for r in featList]]
```

`a` is a list of lists of features (still)
you could do it this way

```
a = [ f for r in featList for f in r]
```

an It's a list of f's, so now you can do what you wanted.

```
[ print(str(f)) for r in featList for f in r]
```

If you see the last part of the List Comprehension section at [Python's Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

you'll see the have the example, for a case like that (double list comprehension)

think of it as a regular `for`

```
# Regular for
for a in A
   for b in A
       f(b)

# Comprehended Loop
a = ( f(b) for a in A for b in a)
```

It's pretty much the same order, except for the statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for list comprehension but you should to rewrite your list comprehension

```
[print(f) for r in featList for f in r]
```

If you want to run

```
[print(str(f)) for f in [r for r in featList]]
```

than you could implement `__repr__` in `Feature`:

```
def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return 'f'
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Mention of __repr__ was helpful.  I tried to upvote, but not enough reputation points yet for that.